# Python - Populate a dictionary with list items

Tags: python, dictionary

If a create a dictionary in this fashion:

```
output = {'playlist': {}}
```

having a `list` like this:

```
tracks = [u'No Surprises', u'Oceans', u'Up in Flames']
```

and with

```
count = 0
```

I would like to populate the key `playlist` with all `tracks` items as `keys` with `0` value, like this:

```
output = {'playlist': {
               'No Surprises': 0,
               'Oceans': 0,
               'Up in Flames': 0}}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You can also use defaultdict if your playlist is going to grow. Read the documentation of collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = {'playlist':{track: count for track in tracks}}
```

Comment: this gets rid of  `key` `'playlists'`inside `dictionary`

Comment: True! Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: please change `0` to `count`and I'll accept your answer as the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> output['playlist'] = dict(zip(tracks, [value for i in tracks]))
>>> output
{'playlist': {u'Up in Flames': 0, u'Oceans': 0, u'No Surprises': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost two years late, but this seems like the ideal use case for [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
output = {'playlist': dict.fromkeys(tracks, count)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for track in tracks:
    output["playlist"][track] = 0
```

Comment: You ought to add a small explanation, since it is a beginner.